# Avoid configuration class as a Singleton

Tags: c++, proxy, singleton

I need to use kind of *Configuration* class, which is used across several other. Part of them are using *Configuration* to read values, some of them are changing them.

What is important - all "read" classes has to stay up to date with configuration. What means - all of them are observing *Configuration* instance.

The first approach - use Singleton pattern. Then *Configuration* is consistent across all other classes.

[image]

Unfortunately it  is hard to test such classes. I want to avoid coupling between Singleton and the rest of my application. Here is my new approach:

[image]

*ConfigurationProxy is created at each class and it is the only one, which is coupled with *Configuration*

Is there a better way to avoid coupling with such a Singleton?

Comment: Why do you think you need a singleton in 1st place for this?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to avoid coupling with such a Singleton?

Yes, don't have a singleton.

This is one reason why I avoid global variables (whether or not you disguise them with some weird antipattern). You tie your code to a particular object, and it can't be tested without that object.

Just define an abstract interface for the configuration, and pass that to everything that needs it. Your tests provide a stub; your real programs provide a real configuration.

Comment: Of course I could have one Configuration, create an object at main and pass it to all classes. I just wish to avoid passing it throughout several layers.